# Returning nth cell in a certain column using summarise in ddply in R

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to return the nth row for each id in a certain column using summarise with ddply. In the example below lets say the 2nd cell for each id in column b.

```
id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)
b <- c(9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 4, NA, NA, 3, 2)
c <- c(2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 5, 3, NA, 4, 7)
df <- data.frame(id,b,c)
df


   a  b  c
1  1  9  2
2  1  9  3
3  2  9  6
4  2  7  7
5  3  5  4
6  3  4  5
7  4 NA  3
8  4 NA NA
9  5  3  4
10 5  2  7
```

I have tried the following:

```
df_2 <- ddply(df, ~a, summarise, 
              b_mean_per_id = mean(b, na.rm = TRUE),
              second_b = nth(df$b, 2))
```

Which only returns the second cell in b (not for each id)

```
 a b_mean_per_id second_b
1 1           9.0        9
2 2           8.0        9
3 3           4.5        9
4 4           NaN        9
5 5           2.5        9
```

But what I want is:

```
 a b_mean_per_id second_b
1 1           9.0        9
2 2           8.0        7
3 3           4.5        4
4 4           NaN        NA
5 5           2.5        2
```

Any hint highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(b_mean = mean(b, na.rm = TRUE), 
            second_b = b[2])

#     id b_mean second_b
#   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1    1.   9.00       9.
#2    2.   8.00       7.
#3    3.   4.50       4.
#4    4.    NA        NA 
#5    5.   2.50       2.
```

---

We can also use `nth` instead of directly sub setting `b`

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(b_mean = mean(b, na.rm = TRUE), 
             second_b = nth(b, 2))
```

Comment: Perfect, simplier than I thought. Thanks a lot :)